# What's the difference between Amazon's official S3.py vs boto.s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I intend to use Amazon S3 in my Django project, what's the difference between Amazon's official `S3.py` and `boto.s3`? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that, by `S3.py`, you are referring to the code available to download [here](http://aws.amazon.com/code/134/). So, please correct me if I am wrong.

In this case, IMHO, boto has some advantages, as pointed out at the [Getting Started with AWS and Python](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998/) tutorial:

> Bar none, boto is the best way to interface with Amazon Web Services (AWS) when using Python. After all, It has been around for years, has grown up alongside AWS, and is still actively maintained.

Boto also has a good documentation, and an active mail list.

On the other hand, take a look at the last documented update to `S3.py`, and particularly when it happened:

> 2007-11-05: Updates to support EU

And this is another thing that got me thinking (remember that Python 3.3.0 beta is out there):

> This sample was built using Python 2.2.3.

So, my recommendation is: you should use boto.

Comment: boto's main author was hired by amazon too if you need more 'endorsement'

Comment: Thanks. Are there significant technical considerations between boto vs S3.py?

Comment: Taking a first look at the [docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/index.html), it is clear that boto is able to use several AWS services (and even some non-AWS ones, like `Google Cloud Storage`. Wow!), while S3.py is obviously for S3 only. I haven't examined the specific S3 features of each one, though.